# Is showing pop up in front of main page good idea from seo perspective?

Tags: seo, google, ranking, google-ranking

We are creating an e-commerce website where if a user lands without the city in the URL, we will open a pop up to ask the user city. As per current design, the city pop-up looks like:

[image: city pop up]

Once user lands here, he has two choices:

1. Type his/her city and land to city-specific product page.
2. Click on cross (top-right) on city popup and land to Pan-Country product page.

I was wondering if google would penalize us for showing pop up content in first fold view to the user.

Comment: I don't think there is a definitive answer. It seems there is a risk of ranking impact because you appear to be covering the content of the page - see: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/08/helping-users-easily-access-content-on.html

Comment: Jan 2017 news: [Google confirms rolling out the mobile intrusive interstitials penalty](http://searchengineland.com/google-confirms-rolling-mobile-intrusive-interstitials-penalty-yesterday-267408)

Comment: Google considers pop-up as bad UX. So do I. I see one and I bounce.

Comment: Sorry but this type of question has been asked in various forms already on Pro Webmasters, one linked is one of several exist that answers the impact of SEO of using popups, with or without relevant content... but to save your time... yes it hampers your SEO potential, does it prevent you ranking? no, just look at Groupon and all the other sites, but that said... I don't use Groupon because I hate having to login or type stuff to navigate around the site when it should be browsable without prompting users to input anything, like gumtree... Popup = Bad UX, Input Popups = Very Bad UX.

Comment: I recommend that you take a stroll over to [UX Stack](https://ux.stackexchange.com) and read the hundreds of questions and answers regarding the UX impact of using popups and modals UX ~ since your priority should be users, not search engines.